# Number of visitors per day

Tags: discussion, site-metrics

I see some statistics on the right side including number of questions, answers, and visitors  per day.

How it is computed? Does it mean registered visitors? Visitors of different IP addresses? Can be search engines/bots included?

(I tagged this question as discussion, as I found no more suitable tag among the avilable tags, maybe update needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post on [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123701/182516) explain how visits/day are calculated for area51 sites. It has several links which answers this question.

Search engines and bots are not included I guess.